# Do aws glue APIs return the partition key fields in order?

Tags: aws-glue, aws-glue-data-catalog

I am pretty new to Glue. We are trying to use glue apis `get_table` and `get_partitions` to get detailed information on glue tables.

`get_table` returns a field `PartitionKeys` which containing all the fields used in partitioning. I am wondering is the order of the field in `PartitionKeys` are guaranteed as how the partition happens?
For example, if our partitioned fold looks like `s3://my_bucket/year=2021/month=07/day=12`, then the fields in `PartitionKeys` will for sure be [{'Name': 'year', ...}, {'Name': 'month', ...}, {'Name': 'day', ...}]?

Based on https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/update-from-job.html they are requiring `Your partitionKeys must be equivalent, and in the same order, between your parameter passed in your ETL script and the partitionKeys in your Data Catalog table schema.`

Can we assume the partition keys are well ordered too?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the partition keys will be returned in the same order as they were specified when the table was created.